# save a value in a preg function

Tags: php, regex

I have this code:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$test = 'this is a #test';
$regex = "#(\#.+)#";
$test = preg_replace($regex, '<strong>$1</strong>', $test);
echo $test;
?>
```

and I would like to do: `$array[] = $1`

Does anyone have a suggestion, please?

Comment: What is `$1`? An argument of some sort?

Comment: You can use phps `preg_replace_callback()` for such purpose.

Comment: @EmilVikström: `$1` is meant to reference a match inside `$regex`.

Comment: @arkascha I didn't get the explonations in php.net, I tried
<?php
function hash($matches)
{
 $test = array();
 $test[]=$matches;
 return '<strong>' . $matches .'</strong>';
}
$test = 'this is a #test';
$regex = "#(\#.+)#";
$test = preg_replace_callback($regex, 'hash', $test);
echo $test;
echo $test[0];
?>

but it doesn't work, it says "Cannot redeclare hash()"

Comment: Sorry, impossible to read that comment. Please edit your question above and add your coding attempts so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHP ≥ 5.3.0 you can use an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). First the callback:

```
$array = array();
$callback = function ($match) use (&$array) {
    $array[] = $match[1];
    return '<strong>'.$match[1].'</strong>';
};

$input = 'this is a #test';
$regex = '/(#.*)/';
$output = preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $input);
echo "Result string:\n", $output, "\n";
echo "Result array:\n";
print_r($array);
```

Results in:

```
Result string:
this is a <strong>#test</strong>
Result array:
Array
(
    [0] => #test
)
```

Before PHP 5.3.0 you can only use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) or any function defined somewhere else in the code. Both of them cannot access the local variable `$array` defined in the parent scope of `$callback`. In this case you would either have to use a global variable for `$array` (ugh!) or define the function inside a class and make `$array` a member of that class.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 4 >= 4.0.5, PHP 5, use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) with `global` variable.

###PHP code:

```
$array = array();
$input = 'this is a #test';
$regex = '/(#\w*)/';
$output = preg_replace_callback(
  $regex,
  create_function(
    '$match', 'global $array; 
     $array[] = $match[1]; return "<strong>" . $match[1] . "</strong>";'),
  $input);
echo "Result string:\n", $output, "\n\n";
echo "Result array:\n";
print_r($array);
```

###Output:

```
Result string:
this is a <strong>#test</strong>

Result array:
Array
(
    [0] => #test
)
```

###Demo:

Click **[here](http://ideone.com/y4KuXh)**.

Comment: +1! Although, you should probably also recommend a member variable over a global one ;)

Comment: The full solution would have 70% different code again ^^, which is why I'm hesitant to include into either of our solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
preg_match($regex, $test, $matches);
$my_array = $matches[1];
```

Comment: He wants to replace parts of the subject as you can tell by the output command towards the end. So your suggestion would mean to run the regex twice.

Comment: Ok @arkascha, I just saw your comment in the question, you're right, he must use preg_replace_callback() for this.